# Restarting from beginning after clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

[link to test site](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2953799/test.html)

I want to restart the animation from the beginning once it stops at the last image. I tried the code below but it won't return to the first image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval("slideshow()", 3000);
});

function slideshow() {
    var time = window.setInterval("slideshow()", 3000);
    next = $(".next");
    inside = parseInt($(".inside").css("left"));

    if (inside == -3080) {
        window.clearInterval(time);
        inside == 0;
    }
    else {
        next.trigger("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code, you have "inside == 0" as a statement. Did you mean to do "inside = 0"? The comparison operator (==) won't change the "inside" variable, whereas the assignment (=) will.

Comment: Watch out for that `next` variable, if you don't declare it as `var next` (i.e.: with the `var` keyword), then it will be created as a global variable, and it could interfere with other code.

Comment: @julio.olvr: There are at least five problems with this code (see my answer). `var` is not the only one, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I am new to javascript so I'll take any suggestions or feedback I can get! You guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your loop you can do this:

```
$(".path0 a").click();
```

Then this will return to first image. So it could become to something like:

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval("slideshow()", 3000);
});

```
function slideshow(){ 
    var time = window.setInterval("slideshow()", 3000);
    next= $(".next");
    inside = parseInt($(".inside").css("left")); 
    if (inside==-3080)
    {
        window.clearInterval(time); 
        $(".path0 a").click(); 
    }
    else {next.trigger("click");}
};
```

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking solely at your code, you have at least three issues:

- you start interval too many times at the beginning (once when document is ready, once when you call the callback),
- you do not use `var` keyword, which is huge mistake,
- you make comparison instead of assignement (`inside==0`),
- you use `==` instead of `===` (which is a bad practice unless you really know what you are doing and `===` does not suit your needs),

Your code could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    slideshow(); // execute once and start interval
});

function slideshow(){
    var time = window.setInterval("slideshow()", 3000);
    var next = $(".next");
    var inside = parseInt($(".inside").css("left")); 

    if (inside === -3080){
        window.clearInterval(time);
        inside = 0;
    } else {
        next.trigger("click");
    };
};
```

(make sure `inside === -3080` comparison is less strict, as mistake by only one pixel will mean the interval will not be cleared - I suppose `inside <= -3080` would be better)

I did not test it, I have just fixed some obvious problems with it.

**EDIT:**

I have just spotted **you start new interval within every interval**. Do not do it. Declare `time` outside of the callback and then, within callback, check whether it has been set or not, then make appropriate actions.

Comment: Why don't you add a bullet point that `window.setInterval("slideshow()", 3000);` can be rewritten as `setInterval(slideshow, 3000);`, thereby avoiding unnecessary code evaluation when we can grab a reference to the function?

Comment: @DawsonToth: At first I saw it, but then I left it, as there were more important problems (such as ambiguity, useless comparisons, messing with global namespace etc.). But you are correct - this should be replaced (although it is not that big).